# AWS Cognito role restrict permissions to invoke Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have a Cognito Identity Pool with an Authenticated role with a policy applied as per below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ab:asdf:function:b",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an API Gateway resource which has AWS_IAM Authorization applied.

Now this only gives access to invoke 1 specific lambda function.

However, I'm able to invoke other lambda functions, I am not restricted to this function only.

When I try the policy simulator, it states that other functions will be `denied`, however this is not the case.

I've confirmed that the request is assuming the correct role, this is what comes through in the request:

```
userArn: "arn:aws:sts::00000000:assumed-role/appAuthRole-dev/CognitoIdentityCredentials"
```

Why would this be?

Comment: Are you using versioning on your lambda functions?

Comment: @HarshaBhat, Yes, does that make a difference?